# SQL*Plus exiting with 0 even when logon denied

Tags: java, sqlplus

I am using a shell script to run a java class which accesses SQL*PLUS. Right now, there's a very peculiar behavior where even if the DB credentials are wrong, sqlplus (ran through java.process) still does not throw an error (exit code 1) or error stream. Instead, it prints the error in the java.process output.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to first make sure sqlplus is run with the `-L` option (Attempts to log on just once, instead of reprompting on error.) then parse the output and if it contains

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

or

```
SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.
```

it means the login failed.

Note: only look for ORA-01017 or SP2-0751 because the string may be localized.